# Can Flyway drop database-level (not schema-level) objects for SQLServer?

Tags: roles, flyway

Flyway operates at the schema level.  What about objects at the database level, e.g. roles?  It seems that these database-level objects are within the scope of what an application owns and could be considered part of its deployment.  Is there any way to manage these things as part of a deployment performed with Flyway?

Answer (score 1):

Flyway has no technical restriction on what you can do in .sql files. As long as the command can be expressed as a sql statement, you should be fine, regardless of whether if affects a specific schema or the entire DB.

The only schema-specific thing is the clean command.